# How to pass a Map<String, String> with application.properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have implemented some authorization in a webservice that needs be configured.

Currently the user/password combo is hardcoded into the bean configuration. I would like to configure the map with users and passwords into the application.properties so the configuration can be external.

Any clue on how this can be done?

```
<bean id="BasicAuthorizationInterceptor" class="com.test.BasicAuthAuthorizationInterceptor">
    <property name="users">
        <map>
            <entry key="test1" value="test1"/>
            <entry key="test2" value="test2"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A [`java.util.Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) object is already a `Map`, actually a `HashTable` which in turn implements `Map`.

So when you create a properties file (lets name it `users.properties`) you should be able to load it using a `PropertiesFactoryBean` or `<util:properties />` and inject it into your class.

```
test1=test1
test2=test2
```

Then do something like

```
<util:properties location="classpath:users.properties" id="users" />

<bean id="BasicAuthorizationInterceptor" class="com.test.BasicAuthAuthorizationInterceptor">
    <property name="users" ref="users" />
</bean>
```

Although if you have a `Map<String, String>` as a type of the users property it might fail... I wouldn't put them in the `application.properties` file. But that might just be me..

Comment: Can you tell us what you've implemented in com.test.BasicAuthAuthorizationInterceptor?

Answer (score 90):

you can use `@Value`.

Properties file:

```
users={test1:'test1',test2:'test2'}
```

Java code:

```
@Value("#{${users}}")
private Map<String,String> users;
```

Comment: This is good! How can we read map from application.yml file? @Value("#{${users}}") is not working if we use application.yml file instead of application.properties file to read properties

Comment: Lets say I've 50 such properties, so I cant keep adding 50 times `@Value("#{${users}}")`, is there any way if we can read all in place? Or in one go?

Comment: Lets say I've almost 50 endpoint,  I cant keep adding `@Value("#{${users}}")`, I need to read all in one go.

Comment: Not sure why this answer is accepted. This works like charm in spring-boot world especially

Comment: What if my value is string[] or custom class, how can read? Ex: `private Map<String, String[]> users;` or `private Map<String, User> users;`

Comment: @Pra_A you can create a bean: `@Bean("users") public Map<String,String> users(@Value("#{${users}}") Map<String,String> users) { return users; }`

Comment: @Pradeep you could inject the Map<String, String> value into a bean that returns the parsed data (using Jackson or your own logic)

Comment: @Pradeep You can also explore using `@ConfigurationProperties`

Comment: Good. Also I had exceptions with injecting my other properties to map in application properties. In that case you can use format: `kafka-topic-by-type={'CRYPTO_PANIC_NEWS': '${kafka.news-topic}'}`

Answer (score 55):

You can use `@ConfigurationProperties` to have values from `application.properties` bound into a bean. To do so you annotate your `@Bean` method that creates the bean:

```java
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties
public BasicAuthAuthorizationInterceptor interceptor() {
    return new BasicAuthAuthorizationInterceptor();
}
```

As part of the bean's initialisation, any property on `BasicAuthAuthorizationInterceptor` will be set based on the application's environment. For example, if this is your bean's class:

```
public class BasicAuthAuthorizationInterceptor {

    private Map<String, String> users = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public Map<String, String> getUsers() {
        return this.users;
    }
}
```

And this is your application.properties:

```
users.alice=alpha
users.bob=bravo
```

Then the `users` map will be populated with two entries: `alice:alpha` and `bob:bravo`.

Here's a small sample app that puts this all together:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args)
                .getBean(BasicAuthAuthorizationInterceptor.class).getUsers());
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties
    public BasicAuthAuthorizationInterceptor interceptor() {
        return new BasicAuthAuthorizationInterceptor();
    }

    public static class BasicAuthAuthorizationInterceptor {

        private Map<String, String> users = new HashMap<String, String>();

        public Map<String, String> getUsers() {
            return this.users;
        }
    }
}
```

Take a look at the [javadoc for `ConfigurationProperties`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.7.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationProperties.html) for more information on its various configuration options. For example, you can set a prefix to divide your configuration into a number of different namespaces:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="foo")
```

For the binding to work, you'd then have to use the same prefix on the properties declared in application.properties:

```
foo.users.alice=alpha
foo.users.bob=bravo
```

Comment: Note that your bean should have a getter in order to spring be able to populate the map and a public field is not enough.

Comment: @MeysaM Have you misread the code? BasicAuthAuthorizationInterceptor already has a `getUsers()` method and the `users` field is `private`, not `public`.

Comment: No, It was just a reminder for everyone else to do not repeat my mistake. Your code works absolutely fine.

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer. Just what I was looking for!

Comment: `metrics.tagsAsSuffix.jvm.gc=` and `metrics.tagsAsSuffix.jvm.threads=` don't get read into `Map<String, List<String>>` with each empty, but `metrics.tagsAsSuffix.jvm` = empty list. The rest of the suffix is dropped

Comment: @AndyWilkinson 
I don't know some how I am getting empty map with the same code. Can you please let me know if anything that I might be missing. Also I have added the same properties in the application.properties as well

Comment: @JainiNaveen There's no way of knowing what you might be missing without seeing some code. Your best bet is to ask a new question with a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](/help/mcve).

Comment: What if we want multiple Map.Entry ?

Comment: @fuat The code above will create two entries in the map: `alice -> alpha` and `bob -> bravo`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something similar

http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/reading-properties-files-in-spring-with-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-bean

You can pick values from .properties similarly and assign it to your map.